# Blender stops responding temporarily when adjusting sliders

Tags: interface, performance, system

The Blender application frequently stops responding temporarily when I attempt to adjust value sliders in the UI. Once it starts responding again I can adjust sliders normally however, five minutes later it will do the same thing again. No errors or info print to the console, it just hangs for several seconds. Any idea why this might be happening?

*Update* - As per suggestion here is some more information about my setup:

- Blender Version: 2.82
- OS Version: Windows 10 Education 64-bit
- CPU: Intel Core i7 3960X (3.30 GHz, 6 Cores, 12 Threads)
- GPU: Radeon RX 580 8192 MB VRAM, GDDR5 2000 MHz (Driver updated
  yesterday)
- RAM: 32GB DDR3

Comment: Hi, welcome! For sure it is not normal behavior. It could depend on your graphics drivers maybe, sometimes weird UI issues are due to that. Try upgrading them to their latest version if possible. Also maybe ad some details about which graphics card and pc (specifications) are you using, and which blender version exactly.

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks for the reply. I updated my GPU drivers yesterday but I have added some more information like you suggested.

Comment: Does it happen on all sliders? What operation are you trying to perform? Sliders usually hang if the underlying calculation is really intensive.

Comment: Any sliders. It will hang if I am changing, say, the location of a basic cube.